# How to remove unnecessary dots in an image and leave only the desired cluster using skimage in Python?

Tags: computer-vision, scikit-image, image-morphology

I have images with certain clusters which I would like to use later in the classification model. However, in all images, I have dots that are unnecessary and I would like to remove them from images. I'm trying to do it using morphological operations in Python with skimage but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is a sample image:

[Sample Image (can't post images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFd68.gif)

Comment: And what have you tried in python so far? As: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import regionprops, label

labels = label(my_image)
props = regionprops(labels)
regions_areas = [props[k].area for k in range(0, np.max(labels))]
```

Then you are free to play around with the regions of small size either to delete them or to discard them and focus your next processing operations on the regions that are the biggest ones.

Your question is very vague in terms of what you call a "cluster" but at least this is a start...